# Revert value from pg_size_pretty, convert to bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can revert to the original value generated with `pg_size_pretty` in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
 c.relname
,pg_size_pretty (pg_relation_size (c.oid))
FROM pg_class c
ORDER BY c.relpages DESC
LIMIT 1;

RESULT:
relname | pg_size_pretty
------------------------
tabla   | 928 MB
```

I need: `928 MB > 973078528`

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `pg_size_pretty()` and use `pg_relation_size()` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in function for this; you'll just have to do it the long way:

```
select split_part(pg_size_pretty, ' ', 1)::bigint *
  case split_part(pg_size_pretty, ' ', 2)
    when 'bytes' then 1
    when 'kB' then 1024
    when 'MB' then 1024*1024
    when 'GB' then 1024*1024*1024
    when 'TB' then 1024*1024*1024*1024::bigint
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

The builtin function for this is [`pg_size_bytes(text)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) and is available from 9.6.

```sql
postgres=# --
select
    pg_size_pretty(973078528::bigint),
    pg_size_bytes('928 MB'),
    (pg_size_bytes('928 MB') > 973078528)::text as "is_bigger"
;
 pg_size_pretty | pg_size_bytes | is_bigger
----------------+---------------+-----------
 928 MB         |     973078528 | false
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

[Try it on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4a3a7074b0f6aa0b3784575ff1210db8)